# Out of memory exception with android google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

When i adding and deleting markers on the map, after some time the app crashes with message out of memory exception.

the logcat response is:

```
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892): FATAL EXCEPTION: vts_com.rapidBizApps.mapamine
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.bb.d.a(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.s.ap.a(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.ak.r.a(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.ak.e.a(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.ak.e.a(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.ak.o.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.ak.e.j_(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.ak.ad.j_(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.bb.l.b(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:27.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1892):     at maps.bb.l.run(Unknown Source)
02-21 06:04:33.260: D/dalvikvm(1892): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2148K, 53% free 5309K/11207K, external 21007K/21768K, paused 71ms
```

my code is:

```
loop 20 times:


    mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                                .fromBitmap((bitmap)))
                                        .snippet(text + "             ")
                                        .title(mine_name));
```

For every new loop,i am removing markers on map and adding new ones.

I also took enough care about bitmap as

bitmap.recycle and assign bitmap with null after use of bitmap/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some issue on this google api. We have to wait the next release....
The BitmapDescriptorFactory have memory leak.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Fixed 25 Jan 13 but not released. Hurry up google!

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue in Google map v2, In my case, my map is refresh at every 30 Seconds. After half an hour my app is crash, I solved this issue using `mMap.clear();` where `mMap`is my object of `GoogleMap`.

You can put this code before calling of for loop.

hope this will help you.